# Eclipse loads the wrong Java Runtime Code downloaded with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded the sources of the runtime of Java using maven command: mvn dependency:sources. The

I have a break point on the class java.util.concurrent.Executors, and the debugger stops in a part of file that has comments: [image]

I am using version 1.6.0_37 in Eclipse, and configured maven with:

```
<configuration>
   <source>1.6</source>
   <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
```

How can I load the same Java Runtime code in the debug? I have also tried to link the "source lookup" with the java library that I am using, but didnt have any influence!

Comment: can you check editor in which your class file is opened. I think it is JD Eclipse class file viewer instead of eclipse one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the problem.
I was debugging in remote and using in Eclipse, Java 6, but starting Tomcat with Java 7.